# How can you get time related to frequency domain behavior? [FourierTransform, SignalProcessing, PowerSpectralDensity]

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing, time-series

**Context:** Data shown is EEG Time domain data transformed to get an alpha brainwave plot with X= Time Units & Y= Intensity/Power of the frequency band of interest.

**Question:** how do you get time data on the x axis after the FourierTransform or after PowerSpectralDensity? Isn't the time data lost, when you do the Fourier Transform?

**How can you get the time data related to different brainwave intensities, if you've already done the Fourier Transform?**

[image]

[image]

**Expected Plot-types:** Plots I would have expected for a procedure like this, shown below.

- **PowerSpectralDensity = FFT (Autocorrelation of a Time Series DataSet)**[image: PowerSpectralDensity]
- **FFT or FT of Time Domain Data**[image]

Also... a related question I have on the DSP StackExchangeSite on Autocorrelation for EEG Signal Processing: [Processes/Transforms involved to get brainwave data from raw EEG? (Autocorrelation confusion)](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/73422/processes-transforms-involved-to-get-brainwave-data-from-raw-eeg-autocorrelati)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the red alpha line graph:

X Axis = Time (in seconds)
Y Axis = Power/Intensity (from the Fourier Transform)

You can know the power within certain time frames, because of windowing, like [welch windows][1].

The raw EEG data was segmented and broke into windows of a window length of time n.

The graph shows alpha powers @ a window.
[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_method